# iPhone Safariの下部連打でスクロールする現象の対策

Tags: javascript, html, iphone, safari

iPhone Safari全般において、画面下部あたりを連打していると
ちょっとずつ下にスクロールしていってしまいます。

ゲームのUIを作っていて、下部にボタンがあるため連打で下に動いて困っています。

この挙動を制御する方法があればアドバイスお願いします！

Answer (score 0, accepted):

自己解決しました。

```
$(window).bind("touchstart touchmove", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```